# Want to repeat my table header of my html page on each page while printing or by exporting to Pdf by any way

Tags: javascript, html, css

Want to repeat my table header of my html page on each page while print preview or by exporting to Pdf by any way. The data in table will not be static it may change dynamically in each td.
I know similar question has been asked here. But didn't found any answer at last for the dynamic data.

```html
 <table >
  <thead>
   <tr >
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Year</th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>September</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>October</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>November</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>September</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>October</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>November</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>September</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>October</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>November</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
    <td>December</td>
    <td>2015</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>September</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>October</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>November</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
    <td>December</td>
    <td>2016</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>September</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>October</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>November</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
    <td>December</td>
    <td>2017</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
    <td>January</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>April</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>June</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>July</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>August</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>September</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>October</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>November</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   <tr >
    <td>December</td>
    <td>2018</td>
   </tr>
   
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What about repeating the table are you having trouble with?

Comment: @MatthewHerbst : Actually as  rows will get added dynamically in table. So,  what i want is after overflow of row in a single page the header of the table should get repeated on each single page with the rows of table.
Thanks for asking.

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @dreamweiver Please check the following link in which i created for u.
https://jsfiddle.net/famgssdL/2/

Comment: how can you say that data is overflown ?

Comment: @dreamweiver Because my data will increase dynamically in "td" or new "tr" , which will be more than one single page.

Comment: its is difficult to predict the end of page on page preview like in your case. only solution i can think over is to manually calculate the height of page and based on that create a new table with header and move the overflowing rows to that table. this process should continue until there is no rows overflowing into new page.

Comment: @dreamweiver Do u have any example as such? Thanks a ton for your efforts.

Comment: no working example as such,since its not usual scenario. anyway it should not be a problem to achieve that. if your populating `tr` from code dynamically, then you can just verify if that row is crossing over to new page[this will be manual job of printing multiple times and assuming how many rows a page can take in], then instead of appending to old table, create a new table and append the row to it. refer this link to know how to add page break to table to move it to new page. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pageba.asp

Comment: @sanjay: if you have found your solution, then can we close this question now ?

Comment: @dreamweiver : Unfortunately no...Page is behaving weird after adding more data in it.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `Page is behaving weird` ? let me brief the logic what I was talking.       **->** assuming page size is 3 rows+header. **->** Add record to table if no of records in table is less than 3 else add page break & create a new table and insert this new record there. **->** Repeat this process until no records left for processing.

Comment: if your using **jquery** also in your script , then creating  a table and adding it to your page should be easy. http://jsfiddle.net/techrevolt/YxMJT/